# Webintent email in phonegap-android?

Tags: android, cordova

I use the phone gap framework for developing android application, my specification is to send a email message, for that I use web intent plugin for sending email, in default i can able to specify subject and body of mail programmatically, but the contact i can't do it programmatically need to done manually. Is there is any other way to send the contact programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap plugins are possibly the best route, although I personally don't understand how to use the sample here:

http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins

Also, try the "mailto" on and anchor:

```
href="mailto:support@desktopwealth.com?subject=Adding E-mail Subject Is Easy&body=content for the body of the email to remind me of a specfic reason, location or purpose for this email"
```

Comment: When using the mailto anchor it gives the message "Unsupported action" when debugging on android