# how to send email from my phonegap application(cross-platform)?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webintent email in phonegap-android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864888/webintent-email-in-phonegap-android)

I am building an application in phonegap(both ios and android).in my app i want to send email to my friends.pls help me by providing any links.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a plugIn for iOS. Add JS and .h and .m file in your project and reference it in your html file.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

You can download emailComposer plugIn from above URL.

For android we can use webIntent plugIn.