# how to send email in phonegap for android?

Tags: cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webintent email in phonegap-android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864888/webintent-email-in-phonegap-android)

I need to send email using phonegap in both android and iphone.I tried with android with this link.

http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/

but it is showing fully with errors.I didnt get any other link for sending email.Can anybody help me in with this.thanks for any help.